# Underlying tiny checkerboard on painted object

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I have my object set up to paint, but as soon as I paint on it, a tiny checkerboard pattern shows up under the paint color?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong: I needed to delete pre-existing textures in the texture tab.